# Mindset behind recursive functions

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to learn recursive functions, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the idea of recursion. I've watched videos on recursions and saw tutorials, but I cant think of the recursion needed when I try to solve them myself. However, I can solve those pretty quickly using loops and iterations.

For example, I saw a question about finding the number of digits in a number, and the answer was:

```
def digit(n):
  if n < 10:
      return 1
  else:
      return 1 + digit(n/10)
```

I know that the `if` is a point where the recursion will stop, but I don't understand how or why the `else` part works even after looking at the answer.

What should my thought process be like when using recursive functions?

Comment: Calling a function recursively is not any different than calling *another function* from a function. `def foo(): return bar()` – same thing. A function is a thing which takes an argument and returns a value (probably). Just put these two pieces together in your head. My function either returns a value, or calls another function (even if that's the same function) which takes my value and returns another value…

Comment: This would be a much better question if you also posted your non-recursive solution to the one you've listed. Will make for a better discussion :)

Comment: The book "The Little Schemer" by Friedman et. al. is a classic introduction to thinking recursively. It doesn't use Python (instead it uses as dialect of Lisp), but the core mindset of recursion is language-independent.

Comment: "In order to understand recursion you must first understand recursion". :)

Comment: You should try to [Google recursion](https://google.com/search?q=recursion). Eventually you will reach enlightenment ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursion is very useful if the problem at hand is recursive as well. One such problem is traversing a tree-like datastructure. Any computer program that is being compiled results in such a structure called the syntax tree. The compiler goes through the tree and generates code for the branches it finds. I know this in itself doesn't help you to comprehend recursion, but it's just to make clear that recursion is a very practical concept. Only the examples given are mostly rather artificial, since the 'real' examples need too much prior knowledge.

As for your example, some prints should make clear what's going on:

```
def digit(n):
    print ('Entering "digit" with n == {}'.format (n))

    if n < 10:
        print ('In the "if" now')
        return 1
    else:
        print ('In the "else" now')
        return 1 + digit(n/10)

print (digit (10000))
```

Following modified code makes it even more clear, try to follow execution step by step:

```
def digit(n):
    print ('\nCalling "digit" with n == {}'.format (n))

    if n < 10:
        print ('In the "if" now for n == {}'.format (n))
        result = 1
        print ('Exiting "digit" from the "if" with n == {}, result now is {}'.format (n, result))
        return result
    else:
        print ('In the "else" now for n == {}'.format (n))
        result = 1 + digit(n/10)
        print ('Exiting "digit" with n == {}, result now is {}'.format (n, result))
        return result


print ('Nr of digits is: {}'.format (digit (10000)))
```

It prints:

```
D:\aaa>call C:\Python35\python.exe so.py 

Calling "digit" with n == 10000
In the "else" now for n == 10000

Calling "digit" with n == 1000.0
In the "else" now for n == 1000.0

Calling "digit" with n == 100.0
In the "else" now for n == 100.0

Calling "digit" with n == 10.0
In the "else" now for n == 10.0

Calling "digit" with n == 1.0
In the "if" now for n == 1.0
Exiting "digit" from the "if" with n == 1.0, result now is 1
Exiting "digit" with n == 10.0, result now is 2
Exiting "digit" with n == 100.0, result now is 3
Exiting "digit" with n == 1000.0, result now is 4
Exiting "digit" with n == 10000, result now is 5
Nr of digits is: 5
```

What also helps is the following: With each call of the function, a new chunk of local data is piled upon something in memory called the stack. In this case that chunk of data is just parameter n which is stored as a local variable. And with each exit of a call (so at one of the returns), this chunk of data is taken off the stack and thrown away. In neat terms: each function call has its own stack frame.

Take some pieces of paper, and for each call (see output), write n on it and put it on a stack. Then for each exit throw away the top paper. While this is no magic bullet it may help your imagination.

Bottom line: it may take you considerable time before a "click" is made in your brain. But it's really worth while. Don't be amazed if it takes a week or longer. That's normal, although not all programmers will admit it. Try to follow program execution step by step, using the output in my answer and a pile of paper notes. After a while: click... Don't stare the problem for longer than a quarter if you get dizzy, try again next day (from experience...).

Note to Python specialists: The 'stack' model in Python is only conceptually, while in e.g. C++ it is real. But it's a good model for the behavior of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The key to recursion is that you're solving a problem by using the solution of a smaller version of the same problem.

In your case, you can count the number of digits by dropping the last digit, then adding in the count of the remaining digits

```
digits(n) = 1 + digits(n/10)
digits(n) = 1 + (1 + digits((n/10)/10))
...
```

At some point, you have to have a concrete value of `digits(n)` or it will go on forever so you define the base case as a known value.  When `n < 10`, we *know* it has only one digit.

This is a very simple example, but recursion can be very powerful for understanding a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This image might help you understand more visually:

[image: continued fraction]

Each of the fractions is another call to your `digit` function, with the change that you stop eventually. Then the program works from the bottom up to calcualte it 'unravelling' the stack of instruction.

It's useful for executing the same instructon *on the results of the previous execution*. Sometimes you can do it more easily with iteration, sometimes you can't. It often means storing less state that has to then be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the function called like this: `digit(100000)`

The first time you get the result `1 + digit(10000)`.

There you have your next call `digit(10000)` which yields `1 + digit(1000)`.

This goes on until you do `digit(1)` which returns 1 and no more function calls.

You have this chain of function calls which are now all active and waiting to be able to complete their `return`-statements:

```
digit(100000) + digit(10000) + digit(1000) + digit(100) + digit(10) + digit(1)
```

Since it ends with `digit(1)` which doesn't call the function again now the `return`-statements get evaluated from the inside out:

```
digit(100000) + digit(10000) + digit(1000) + digit(100) + digit(10) + 1
digit(100000) + digit(10000) + digit(1000) + digit(100) + 2
digit(100000) + digit(10000) + digit(1000) + 3
digit(100000) + digit(10000) + 4
digit(100000) + 5
6
```

Maybe it helps to view every called function as a separate entity which just follows simple logical rules. It calls another function, takes its return value and creates its own return-value. Nothing more. The concrete instance of the function and its definition are two different things, like the same class can exist several times even though it's only defined once.

Answer (score 0):

I will try my best to explain you as it was quite daunting for me too. At this stage you might find that solving a problem using loops is easier than solving it using recursion, but once you get your head around it you may find it differently.

Lets take some example problems that can be solved using recursion:

**Example 1:** Calculating factorial of a number.

We know n!=n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...1. Now while solving a problem using recursion you must ask would the problem be any simpler if you knew the answer to any of its subproblem(s). In this case you can see it would be a lot easier if you just knew the answer to (n-1)! as n*(n-1)! would give you the desired result.

So when writing code for this problem you don't need to think about anything else other than what we already discussed. So lets write factorial function using just what we know till now:

```
def factorial(n):
    return n*factorial(n-1)
```

While writing this line `return n*factorial(n-1)`, don't think about how is it going to compute the result, just assume that computer is going to compute `factorial(n-1)` for you correctly and return you the result.(Don't think about it for now, but later you must understand how recursion works using stacks. Try to simulate recursive programs using pen and paper to make things a lot clearer).

So for now you don't need to worry about how things will work in the background, but by just looking at this code you can see it is never ending. So to put an end to the process you just add a base case. Base case is the simplest of the cases whose result you can tell just by looking at the problem. In this case you can say if `n=0`, the result should be `1`. So just add this line in your code which now becomes:

```
def factorial(n):
    if(n==0):
        return 1
    return n*factorial(n-1)
```

**Example 2:** Calculate positive integral power of a positive number.

Now you have to calculate`x^n` and you know that if you knew `x^(n-1)` then you could easily calculate `x^n` using `x*x^(n-1)`. You further know the answer to the simplest of such problem, that is, `x^0=1`, that is if `n` is `0` then result should be `1`. So now you can write its code too as we did for the previous case.

Practise more recursive problems and simulate all of them using pen and paper to get a better idea of how the things work. And specially simulate [this](http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-for-tower-of-hanoi/) code to get a better idea of recursion. Hope it helps.